# Create function that applies flag based on other dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
date            id      type
02/02/2020      2       A
29/02/2020      2       B
04/03/2020      2       B
02/01/2020      3       B 
15/01/2020      3       A 
19/01/2020      3       C
...             ...     ...
```

I want to create a new column, called `flagged`. For each row, I want the value of `flagged` to be equal to `True` if there exists another row with

- The same id
- Type A
- A date for which the difference in days with the date of the current row is bigger than 0 and smaller than 30

I would want the dataframe above to be transformed to this

```
date            id      type    flagged
02/02/2020      2       A       False
29/02/2020      2       B       True
04/03/2020      2       B       False
02/01/2020      3       B       False
15/01/2020      3       A       False
19/01/2020      3       C       True
...             ...     ...     ...
```

**My Approach:**

I created the following function

```
def check_type(id, date):
    if df[(df.id == id) & (df.type == 'A') & (date - df.date > datetime.timedelta(0)) & (date - df.date < datetime.timedelta(30))].empty:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

so that if I run

```
df['flagged'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_type(x.id, x.date), axis = 1)
```

I get the desired result.

**Questions:**

1. How do I change the function `check_type` so that it can be applicable to any dataframe, no matter its name? The current function only works if the dataframe that it is used on is called `df`.
2. How do I make this process faster? I want to run this function on a large dataframe, and it's not performing as fast as I would want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For question 1, maybe you can add `df` as an input parameter like `def check_type(id, date, df):`. In this way, when you call the function, you can use any dataframe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I think that's possible, but I'm afraid that it would be very slow, as it would mean that I would pass a big dataframe to the function for every row.

Comment: @titusAdam No copy happens when you pass a variable as a parameter, so Junkrat response is a possible answer. It will be as fast as your current solution

Comment: Of course! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find the last date with `A` type and propagate it throughout the `id` with `ffill` and find the difference:

```
last_dates = df.date.where(df['type'].eq('A')).groupby(df['id']).ffill()

# this is the new column
df.date.sub(last_dates).lt(pd.to_timedelta('30D')) & df['type'].ne('A')
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

**Note**: this works given that you *always* mask `A` with `False`.